# Lazy load sub entity collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a product entity and a child product entity as such:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual ICollection<ProdAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildProduct> Children { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class ChildProduct
{
    public virtual ICollection<ProdAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Parent { get; set; }
    public string ParentItemID { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

In my context, I just grab the products and their children using the following:

```
        return _axaptaContext.Products
            .Include(x => x.Children)
            .Include(x => x.Attributes);
```

Now I want the children to include the attributes as well so I tried to use

```
        return _axaptaContext.Products
            .Include(x => x.Children)
            .Include("Children.Attributes")
            .Include(x => x.Attributes);
```

But this causes the query to timeout.  How do I lazy load the attributes for the children as when I tried to call:

```
product.Children.Attribtutes
```

It just returns null.  Everything I have found about lazy loading says the attributes should be lazy loaded if I mark them as virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you do not need to call `.Include("Children.Attributes")` to **lazy** load instead it is for **eager** loading of entity.

Just make sure that you had set `LazyLoadingEnabled` & `ProxyCreationEnabled` to true on context object. Now when you would call the get on the property sql to fetch the entity would automatically get fired and you will get the object filled.

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Note: property you want to lazy load needs to be virtual.

Comment: I'd done the `LazyLoadingEnabled` but didn't realise the `ProxyCreationEnabled` needed to be true too.  Thanks this worked!